# How to Update parameters every certain steps?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using a tensorflow based keras to train a object detection network.

Due to small GPU memory size, have to update params once per some steps to "expand" batch size.
But my implementation can't successfully converge in Mask Rcnn training or perform badly comparing normal optimizers in simple cifar10 classification:

```
class custom_SGD(Optimizer):
def get_updates(self, loss, params):
    """Main params updates operation
    """
    shapes = [K.int_shape(p) for p in params]
    if self.nesterov:
        sum_grads = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]

    moments = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
    sum_moments = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]

    # Current gradients
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
    self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)] 
    self.weights = [self.iterations] + moments

    cond1 = K.equal(self.iterations % self.steps_per_update, 0)

    # Learning rate decay
    lr = self.lr
    if self.initial_decay > 0:
        lr = lr * (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations,
                                                  K.dtype(self.decay))))
    if not self.nesterov:
        for p, g, m,sm in zip(params, grads,moments, sum_moments):
            v = self.momentum*m - lr*g
            # updates sum_moments, moments
            self.updates.append(K.update(sm, sm+v))
            self.updates.append(K.switch(cond1,K.update(m,sm/float(self.steps_per_update)),m))

            new_p = p + m
            # Apply constraint
            if getattr(p, 'constraint', None) is not None:
                new_p = p.constraint(new_p)
            self.updates.append(K.switch(cond1,K.update(p,new_p),p))
            # Clear up container
            self.updates.append(K.switch(cond1,K.update(sm,K.zeros_like(sm)),sm))

    return self.updates
```

Can anybody tell me why. 
Thanks in advance.